# Variable Matrix name in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to read multiple files in a loop and trying to store the content of the files in a Matrix,i.e. for each file in the loop i want to store the content in a new Matrix. But I couldn't find any method to do that using c++. So I am asking the c++ experts is there any way out?

Any suggestion is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Your heading doesn't match your question

Comment: Please be more specific. What data structure would you use to represent the matrix? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(ysize, std::vector<int>(xsize));` to store a matrix and access elements as `matrix[y][x]`

Answer (score 3):

A solution to your problem would probably be to store your matrices in some container (std::vector, std::list, std::array, depending on your specific needs).

To clarify:
If one matrix is a

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>
```

you are looking for a

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>
```

or

```
std::list<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>
```

etc.

code example: (substitute Matrix by whatever type you use to represent one matrix)

```
std::vector<Matrix> M;
for (...)
{ ... // read new Matrix into Matrix newM
   M.push_back(newM);
}
```

Then your matrices are "called" M[0],M[1],...,M[n-1] if you have n matrices.

Comment: What I want is like for the first file in the loop I want to store the content in say M1 ,for second file in M2, and so on.

Comment: I do not think that this is possible, but if you use std::vector, you can access the matrices e.g. via M[0], M[1] etc. (edited answer again for clarity)

Comment: Please give me some documentation link how to do that.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Can you please explain your last part of the answer i.e. std:vector<Matrix> M a little bit more, because I am not getting the concept how I will get the matrices as M[0],M[1] etc.

Comment: A vector is a container, i.e. something to collect several objects of the same type (e.g. Matrices, but could also be ints, chars, ...).  Your vector has a name (in this case M you decide that when declaring std::vector<Matrix> M;). You add things to your vector (at the back) via M.push_back. To get the first element in the vector you write M[0], M[1] for the second element etc. If your vector were called James it would be James.push_back and James[0]. I hope this explains it. Otherwise googling std::vector should lead to detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It solved my problem and my concept about std::vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have some Matrix implementation to store content of a single file than you could you std::vector to store Matrices corresponded to different files

```
std::vector< Matrix_t > matrices;   
for(...) // loop over the files
{ 
    Matrix_t matrix;
    ... // read file into the matrix
    matrices.push_back(matrix);
}
```

At the end of the loop you will have the vector that contains one matrix per each file.

Comment: What is Matrix_t in your code?

Comment: it is some data type that represent a Matrix that stores file data.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a map, either `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.  This will allow you to map a string to a matrix, eg:

```
std::map<std::string, Matrix> matrices;
matrices.insert( std::make_pair( fileName, getMatrixFromFile( fileName )  ) );
```

and so on.